# how to set style for multiple id element javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code like this:

```
document.getElementById('one').style.color = 'red';
document.getElementById('two').style.backgroundColor= 'blue';
.......
document.getElementById('another').style.fontSize= '20px';
```

Is there a generic method to set style for multiple id element something like below ( like jQuery ) ?

```
document.getElementById('one').add('two').add('three').style.color = 'red';
```

Or, how can I make one?

Comment: That's generally what CSS classes are for. Are you prevented from editing the HTML source?

Comment: You can use getElementsByClassName("class name").
Because Id is unique and classes can be used as common.

Comment: Can you give some sample code of your HTML markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select multiple id's in javascript once. You can do this by giving then same class name.

```
[ 'one', 'two', 'three' ].forEach(function( id ) {

    document.getElementById( id ).style.color = "red";

});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a1cptfdc/)

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted to know is like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
$("input").css('color', 'red');
```

You can also add class to your targeted dom elements that you want to change instead of selected all the input elements. ex:

```
<input id="one" class="whatever" ... etc>
<input id="two" class="whatever" ... etc>
<input id="three" class="whatever" ... etc>
```

And with this javascript to change them

```
$(".whatever").css('color', 'red');
```

More details about selectors at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) or [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Do it through the use of CSS. set the same class for each of these elements:

```
<div id="one" class="class1">text</div>
<div id="two" class="class1">text</div>
<div id="three" class="class1">text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class1 { color: blue }
```

then change it in Javascript with the use of JQuery like:

```
$('.class1').css({"color":"blue"});
```

It's more efficient and better understandable.